# make div span vertically all available height

Tags: html, css

[image]
The red and the green divs are aligned one next to another. How can  make the red div be the same height as the green div?

Comment: Could you add your current HTML/CSS? A [jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/) would also be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a div that contains both elements and is [clearfixed](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/)

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
</div>
```

You then add position relative to the wrapper:

```
.wrapper {
  /* remember this is clearfixed */
  position: relative;
}
```

You let the green container float to the right:

```
.green {
  float: right;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Then you position absolute the red and let it know that it should use all the space of the wrapper:

```
.red {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 50%;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

Note that this case will only work when the green container is larger than the left one.

Answer (score 0):

That is problematic - because to make heights same, you need to add div between document and red and green div, this div must have height defined, so you can set heights for both div-s inside to 100% eg.

```
<div style="height: [must be defined]">
   <div id="red" style="height: 100%; ..."> ... </div>
   <div id="green" style="height: 100%; ..."> ... </div>
</div>
<div id="black" style="height: 100%; ..."> ... </div>
```

BUT - this will break, when one of the divs will be higher than other - fix it by using overflow

PS. For some cases it is good to use tables here, since table cells have always same height

Answer (score 0):

You can use a table as wrapper. First and last tr are optional. But if you need first or last tr so set a height. browser needs this to calculate correct height for middle tr.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {height:100%; padding:0; margin:0;}
    #wrapper {height:100%;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;}
    #wrapper td {vertical-align:top;}
    #wrapperFirst, #wrapperLast {height:1px;}
</style>
<body>
    <table id="wrapper">
        <tr><td id="wrapperFirst" style="background-color: #ff44ff;">foo top</td></tr>
        <tr><td style="background-color: #ffff44;">text</td></tr>
        <tr><td id="wrapperLast" style="background-color: #44ffff;">foo bottom</td></tr>
    </table>

</body>
</html>
```